# Cannot find the proper base case for a recursive function to 'generate' matrices?

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, matrix, generator

I have a recursive function to generate matrices, called `lights`.

This function is called in `light_and_color`.

`light_col_permutation`, called in `lights`, gives a vector of vector of vector of int.

So, in the loop `for(vector<vector<int> > aa:light_col_permutations(rowSums, colSums, colIndex))` in the code, `aa` gives a pair of vector.

`aa[0]` is the possible values that could go into the row of the matrix at index `colIndex`.

`aa[1]` is the updated (remaining) `rowSums` that could be filled in, for unfilled rows after `colIndex`. This is passed into `lights` recursively, to fill in the next column.

What this function is supposed to do is to find **all** matrices for each of `aa` in `light_col_permutations`.

With the base case in the code, it only finds one such matrix and quits(`return`s).

How can I generate all of them?

The following code is a simplified version, so that you can see the structure of the recursion. Please let me know if there is anything unclear. (the whole program is about 800 lines long, but I will post it if requested)

```
void lights(vector<int>& rowSums, vector<int>& colSums, int colIndex, matrix_c mc) {
    if(colIndex == mc.r) {
        mc.print_matrix();
    }
    for(vector<vector<int> > aa:light_col_permutations(rowSums, colSums, colIndex)) {
        mc.row_assign(colIndex, aa[0]);
        mc.newRowSum = aa[1];

        lights(mc.newRowSum, colSums, colIndex+1, mc);
    }
}

void light_and_color(int r, int n, int color, string filename) {
        matrix_c mc(r, n); //zero matrix of size (r) X (r)
        //here I get rowSums and colSums, but I omitted them
        lights(rowSums, colSums, 0, mc);
}
```

Comment: Add more context to your question, please. What are you exactly trying to do?